# Deploy war on tomcat to another folder name

Tags: tomcat

I'd like know is there a way to deploy war copied to webapps folder with another name, of course automatically, and with minimal configuration some xml files.

Example: I have a.war and want AServer folder and service but don't "a" folder and service

Thanks Pavel

EDIT 29.9.11 (7:30): I have something like this for copying in server.xml

```
<Context docBase="a" path="/AServer" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:a" />
```

it's be good if exist some parameters thats delete a folder or some other xml thats disable starting "a" server

EDIT 29.9.11 (14:53)
I found some way. Added deployIgnore="a.war, a" parameters to server.xml - Host and  Context is almost same and almost working (doesn't read a context in conf/Catalina/localhost), but still a folder exist to and probably this is not a good way.

```
 <Context docBase="a" path="/AServer" reloadable="true" />
```

Have someone better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Tomcat's The Context Container documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html):

> path
>
> ...
>
> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a
>   Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be
>   inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or
>   the docBase.

One solution is renaming the war file. Another is unzipping it to the `AServer` folder as @mooreds suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the a.war file, move it to AServer, and remove the a.war file and folder.

There are ant takss for unzipping, moving and deleting that can automate this.